# Eclipse workspace showing maven dependencies are not in build path

Tags: java, maven, myeclipse

I converted an eclipse project to maven with the Maven4MyEclipse plugin, converted the project structure to maven standards (src/main/java, etc..), added all the dependencies in the pom, edited the user settings for maven so that the dependencies are downloading from the company's repository. My local repo has all the dependencies in it when I update project or download sources but I'm still showing errors in the editor. 
I also ran mvn eclipse:eclipse in the project directory and eclipse error log shows

> eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.7.0_45 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32,
>   NL=en_US Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86
>
> Error Thu Apr 07 14:00:09 CDT 2016 Unable to update index for
>   art_central|http://maven/artifactory/libs-snapshot:
>   C:\Software\Maven\repo.cache\m2e\1.4.0\3532f6eda485b47ee5bbcc1113190690\nexus-maven-repository-index.zip
>   (The system cannot find the file specified)

And I am also seeing an error in the error log that says it cannot find files and its looking at the old directory structure

> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource
>   '/Automation/src/main/dru/pageActions/ARHistory.java' does not exist.

the actual path should be /Automation/src/main/java/dru/pageActions/ARHistory.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a valid maven project now (i.e. you can build it fine outside MyEclipse, with an external maven installation) then try stripping it of eclipse files and settings (outside of MyEclipse), then import it as a maven project into MyEclipse. This should get it all set up properly as a MyEclipse project with the maven nature.

It looks like the project source folders (as seen in the Build Path properties page) aren't set properly. Also, running mvn eclipse:eclipse is not necessary, with MyEclipse, and may cause problems. Hopefully, that will all be fixed by importing as a maven project.